# Azure WebJobs ServiceBus returns Exception: found 2 DNS claims in authorization context

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-webjobssdk

I'm trying to read a message from an Azure ServiceBus queue using an Azure WebJob but it's throwing and exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Found 2 DNS claims in authorization context.
```

I've set the correct connection strings named "AzureWebJobsServiceBus", "AzureWebJobsDashboard" and "AzureWebJobsStorage"

The WebJob Program code has been updated to use JobHostConfiguration:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.UseServiceBus();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

And the actual Job method

```
public class Functions
{
    public async static Task ServiceBusResizeRequest(
         [ServiceBusTrigger("blah")] string message,             
         TextWriter log
         )
    {            
        await log.WriteLineAsync("got message " + message);
    }

}
```

I can successfully create and write to the queue via a separate console application.

But when I run the webjob application, it throws that exception.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Using .net 4.6.1

Comment: Downgrading from .net 4.6.1 to 4.6 seems to prevent the issue from occuring. I'll leave this open for a bit longer to see if anyone has an answer as to why 4.6.1 fails

Comment: Well, the WebJobs SDK targets 4.5. we'll release an update moving to 4.6 soon, but that might be the issue.

Comment: Cheers, thanks. Didn't realize it targets 4.5 only.

Comment: One of you should submit this as an answer so it's easier for the next person to find this. :)

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Just to note we have the same problem without the WebJobs SDK, calling Service Bus with a regular SubscriptionClient on 4.6.1.  We couldn't get the AppContextSwitchOverrides fix below to work, either in the Web.config of the service making the call or the App.config of the project where our service bus client is, but a downgrade to 4.6 fixed the issue.

Comment: Odd. I sent a note to the SB team.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

January 29th Microsoft released version 3.1.3 of the NuGet package **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus**.

From the release notes:

*• General: .Net 4.6.1+ compatibility fix. Fixing custom DNS IdentityVerifier so that we honor multiple DNS claims returned by WIF*

Upgrading the package solved the problem for us.

Comment: version 3+ of WindowsAzure.ServiceBus breaks SignalR

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3548

Answer (score 45):

The answer marked as solution, is not the solution, it is a botched job.
The solution to use it in .Net Framework 4.6.1 is to add in the rutime block in App.config:

```
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate=true" />
```

Read this article [Mitigation: X509CertificiateClaimSet.FindClaims Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt620030(v=vs.110).aspx)

Very **IMPORTANT** for now Azure WebApps / WebJob etc, doesn't support 4.6.1 I will note here when (said at jan 21, 2016).

It means, that you can develop a web job application with 4.6.1, but when you push it to Azure, you can see exceptions like `Job failed due to exit code -2146232576`

Comment: Had the same problem. For some reason this AppContextSwitchOverrides setting in config did not help, so I just added the code in constructor             AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate", true);

Comment: Perhaps you have the Context file in different project. Have you tried to add the setting in the app.config of the application and in the project with context too?

Comment: I have an Azure worker role project and tried to apply this configuration to app.config  <runtime> section.

Comment: for us was upgraded from 4.5.2 to 4.7.2 - this solution solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

As outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594127/4090370) above, the snippet below does the trick

```
<runtime>
    ...
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate=true" />
    ...
<runtime>
```

**BUT** be carefull to add it to the correct **project** in your **solution**! Add it to the project containing the Azure code and Azure references.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a new package (under a new name) to fix this issue. So ...

- remove the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus` package,
- install the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus3` package instead, and
- upgrade the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package.

More info here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3548#issuecomment-296326048

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from .net 4.6.1 to 4.6 seems to prevent the issue from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I ran into this issue and had no idea about it. Finally, I decided to upgrade all the Azure nuget packages that I am using (including webjobs, servicebus ...) and BOOM! it WORKS. Hopefully, it will help if anyone runs into this issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

For me it started failing after I updated .NET Framework from 4.5.2 to 4.7
All I did to fix it was update the Nuget Package **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to 5.2.0**