# AppContextSwitchOverrides doesn't work, found 3 DNS claims in authorization context

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I get "found 3 DNS claims in authorization context" in my role on azure. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329056/azure-webjobs-servicebus-returns-exception-found-2-dns-claims-in-authorization) but it doesn't work. At first I added the config setting

```
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate=true" />
```

It doesn't help.

Then I tried with setting by code

```
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMul‌​tipleDNSEntriesInSAN‌​Certificate", true);

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

The result is the same. I have installed the service bus version 2.7.6 and .net 4.6.2.
I cannot update the service bus to a higher version because signalR won't work with a service bus version >= 3.

Comment: ``I have installed service bus version 2.7.6 , .net 4.6.2 . I cannot update service bust to higher version because signalR won't work with service bus version >= 3`` Are you using the Service Bus backplane to distribute messages? do you try to downgrade .net 4.6.2 to .net 4.5?

Comment: Yes,and I really don't want to downgrade .net version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure WebJobs ServiceBus returns Exception: found 2 DNS claims in authorization context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329056/azure-webjobs-servicebus-returns-exception-found-2-dns-claims-in-authorization)

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was in `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus` NuGet incompatibility with .NET 4.7.1 so that I had to install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus3` instead

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample using the Service Bus backplane to distribute messages to each role instance, which works fine on my side. Please refer to it and test it on your side.

*configure the backplane in Startup.cs class*

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    string connectionString = "<Service Bus connection string>";
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, "FeHanSignalRChat") { TopicCount = 3 });

    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

*packages.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net462" />
    <package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="2.1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

Messages could be distributed fine, and on Azure portal, I could find topics and subscriptions are created.

[image]